# removing the {} from the output

Tags: matrix

I have two matrices

```
m1 ={{a,1},{1,1},{b,1},{c, 1}} 
m2 ={{a,2},{1,2},{b,2},{c,2}}
```

I would like to generate a new matrix m such that m={{m1},{m2}}. So how can I do that?

Comment: `Join[m1, m2]`? Or `Join[{m1},{m2}]`.

Comment: But Join[{m1},{m2}] dosen't work due to the extra {}. I mean If I would like to obtain m={m1,m2} how can i do it

Comment: You might also want to look at [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html), e.g. `ArrayFlatten[{{m1}, {m2}}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
m1 ={{a,1},{1,1},{b,1},{c, 1}}; 
m2 ={{a,2},{1,2},{b,2},{c,2}};
m = Join[m1, m2, 2]
```

which gives `{{a,1,a,2},{1,1,1,2},{b,1,b,2},{c,1,c,2}`, or

```
m1 ={{a,1},{1,1},{b,1},{c, 1}}; 
m2 ={{a,2},{1,2},{b,2},{c,2}};
m = Join[m1, m2]
```

which gives

> `{{a,1},{1,1},{b,1},{c,1},{a,2},{1,2},{b,2},{c,2}}`

If you want to format it as a matrix, you can do

```
m = MatrixForm[Join[m1, m2]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ...and to join by columns instead of by rows: `Join[m1, m2, 2]`.

Comment: @J.M., yes, thanks for pointing that out. =)

Comment: @heather., Thank you! I got it perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Various ways of doing the same:

```
Join[m1, m2]
m1~Join~m2
Join[##] & @@ {m1, m2}
Join[#1, #2] & @@ {m1, m2}
```

Let's call the output `out`:

> {{a, 1}, {1, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 1}, {a, 2}, {1, 2}, {b, 2}, {c, 2}}

You can act on `{{m1},{m2}}` if that produces the desired output, or

```
Length[m1] == Length[m2]
```

> True

```
Partition[out, Length @ m1]
```

> {{{a, 1}, {1, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 1}}, {{a, 2}, {1, 2}, {b, 2}, {c, 2}}}

Or, if the lists are of unequal lengths, e.g.

```
m3 = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}
m4 = {{d, 4}, {e, 5}}

out2 = Join[m3, m4]
```

> {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}, {e, 5}}

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[out2, {3, 2}]
```

> {{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}, {{d, 4}, {e, 5}}}

or more automatically

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[out2, Map[Length, {m3, m4}]]
```

> {{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}, {{d, 4}, {e, 5}}}

Comment: ., Thank you very much!